# how to print array in underscore.js template?

Tags: underscore.js

I am using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)'s templating library, and I am not sure how to go about using a logic inside of a template. for example, I would like to print an array of tags in a template. What is the best approach for this?

Javascript:

```js
bunny_data = {
  name: "sprinkles",
  age: 1,
  tags: ['fuzzy','wuzzy']
};

bunny_view = $("#bunny-template").html();
$(body).append(_.template(bunny_view,bunny_data));
```

Template:

```html
<script type='text/template'>
  <div> 
     <h5><% = name %></h5>
     <ul class='tag-list'>
         <!-- How do I print the tags here? -->
     </ul>
  </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You don't need to encapsulate `bunny_data` as @Ken suggests, you were on the right track. Whether or not you want to call `_.` functions or just use plain Javascript constructs is up to you, but there's no built-in flow constructs in Underscore templates, to do that you just embed code (you might want to look into [eco](https://github.com/sstephenson/eco) or [Mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) or something if you want that).

My example looks like this (almost the same as you own):

```
<script type='text/template' id="bunny-template">
  <div> 
     <h5><%= name %></h5>
     <ul>
       <% for(var tag in tags) { %>
           <li><%= tags[tag] %></li>
       <% } %>
     </ul>
  </div>
</script>
```

with the following Javascript:

```
bunny_data = {
  name: "sprinkles",
  age: 1,
  tags: ['fuzzy','wuzzy']
};

bunny_view = $("#bunny-template").html();
$(body).append(_.template(bunny_view, bunny_data));
```

You can verify that it runs [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jacob414/zgWwX/).

(On a personal preference note, I'm a heavy user of all of Underscore except the templates for this reason, I'm not comfortable with the amount of code you must put in them if you have a more complicated use case).

Comment: whats the difference between <%=%> and <%%>?

Comment: <%= %> outputs the result the expression inside it's clause, <% %> simply executes the code inside it's clause (if you `return` in a <% %>, it will be functionally equivalent to <%= %> though). E.g: <% 'foo' %> outputs nothing, <%= 'foo' %> outputs `foo`.

Comment: Jacob Oscarson has the best way but this is now obsolete.
the new javascript should be with the following Javascript : bunnyview = _.template($("#bunny-template").html());
$(body).append(bunnyview(bunny_data));

Answer (score 8):

It looks like you are not setting `bunny_data` properly in your JavaScript.

Instead of:

```
$(body).append(_.template(bunny_view,bunny_data));
```

Try:

```
$(body).append(_.template(bunny_view, { bunny_data: bunny_data }));
```

Print the data in your template (notice I removed the space after % in `<%= name %>`):

```
<script type='text/template'>
  <div> 
    <h5><%= name %></h5>
    <ul class='tag-list'>
      <% _.each(bunny_data, function(bd) { %>
        <li><%= bd.name %></li>
        ...
      <% }); %>
    </ul>
  </div>
</script>
```

Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 8):

Also `join` will do the trick, so in html you'll have

```
 <ul>
     <li><%= tags.join('</li><li>') %></li>
 </ul>
```

Check it at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R6aCd/).

Comment: no offense but to interject `'</li><li>'` per item seems pretty hacky

Comment: Hacky but the most concise