# How to create a table view Using Backbone collection

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

Currently i have a backbone code like following

```
app.View.FriendRequestListViewModal = Backbone.View.extend( {
template: _.template($('#friend-request-list-modal').html()),

tagName: 'div',

initialize: function(){
   this.render();
},

render: function() {
    $(this.el).html(this.template({
        friendRequestCollection: this.collection}));
    return $(this.el);
},
});
```

and than I have a template like following

```
<script type="text/template" id="friend-request-list-modal">
<table class="table table-hover">
        <@ friendRequestCollection.each(function(user) { @>
            <tr id="<@= user.get('username') @>">
               <td>
                 <img class="pull-left avatar" src="/img/staff_avatar_profile.jpg"
               </td>
               <td>
                 <a href="/tatami/profile/<@= user.username @>/"><@= user.get('firstName')  @>&nbsp;<@= user.get('lastName')  @></a>
               </td>
               <td>
                     <div class="btn-group">
                       <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><fmt:message key="user.request.action"/>
                         <span class="caret"></span>
                      </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                           <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-ok"></i><fmt:message key="user.add.accept.request"/></a></li>
                           <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-remove"></i><fmt:message key="user.add.reject.request"/></a></li>
                       </ul>
                     </div>
               </td>
             </tr>
        <@ }); @>
       </table>
     </script>
```

But now i wanted to create the same table using backbone because I have two buttons in this table which have the following models and I want to include these models using backbone. If u create the buttons using template than I think I will not be able to attach these models to those buttons. Do anybody have any suggestion..

```
app.Model.FriendRequestAcceptModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
url : function(){
  return '/rest/friend/accept';
}
});

app.Model.FriendRequestCancelModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
url : function(){
  return '/rest/friend/reject';
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Majority people use like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648629/how-to-print-array-in-underscore-js-template) ( same to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853039/loops-in-underscore-js-template)), but i prefer do like that: i make separate two template, firstly, i will render first, after then will call the second with collection, and would add second template's result to first.