# Looping an array in a model with Backbone and handlebars

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm developing an app with backbone and handlebars for the Bus timetable of my city. The model of one stop is :

```
    define(["jquery", "underscore", "backbone"],
      function ($, _, Backbone){

    var stop = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults : {
            id : "23",
            lon : "43,465187",
            lat : "-80,522372",
            listabus : ["80", "83", "106"]

        }

    });

    return stop;

});
```

Where "Listabus" is the list of all the bus that pass near the stop number 23. I don't know how I can loop the array in the template...help me! :D thanks in advice

Comment: what is the template engine you are using?

Comment: Have you read the [handlebars documentation](http://handlebarsjs.com/)?

Comment: i'm using underscore.js! I've seen the docs but it didn't answer to my question.

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8657621/1446146) might help you

Answer (score 2):

This is your html:

```
<!-- below is your template !-->
<script id="bus-stops" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<ul>
    {{#each stops}}
    <li>{{this}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
</script>

<!-- result container !-->
<div id="result"></div>
```

And js code

```
   var BusStop = Backbone.Model.extend(),
       busStop = new BusStop({stops: ['a', 'b', 'c']});
       template = $('#bus-stops').html(),
       compiler = Handlebars.compile(template),
       html = compiler({stops: busStop.get('stops')});

   $('#result').html(html);
```

Sorry jsfiddle won't work with handlebars

Answer (score 1):

You just need to pass in your model attributes as an object into the underscore template function. The first argument is the template, the second - your data. You can pass in any object data but underscore plays real nice with model.toJSON() for obvious reasons.

```
this.$('#insertWherever').html(_.template($('#busList'), stopModel.toJSON()));
```

And your template would look something like this.

```
<script id="busList" type="text/html">
<ul>

  <% _.each(listabus, function(busNumber){ %>

    <li><%= busNumber %></li>

  <% }); %>

</ul>
</script>
```

To summarize, the `<% %>` is a way to escape and run arbitrary JS code.
The `<%= %>` is a way to interpolate or output stuff into your template.

See http://underscorejs.org/#template and http://underscorejs.org/#each

If you're using require.js, you can download a plugin called text!

This allows you to define HTML files in your dependencies and have your templates reside in their own individual files. This is opposed to the above method which uses an embedded script tag and jquery to grab the template from within whatever view you're working with.

See plugins / text @ http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html

Comment: very very nice!Actually I use require,so you answered to a question that I wanted to ask !  Thank you so much, it works perfectly :D

Comment: Cool. If it solved the problem, please don't forget to check correct answer. ;)