# Javascript templates using underscore.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I have a phones array that contains data from json:

```
var phones = [
        {
            "age": 0,
            "id": "motorola-xoom-with-wi-fi",
            "imageUrl": "img/phones/motorola-xoom-with-wi-fi.0.jpg",
            "name": "Motorola XOOM\u2122 with Wi-Fi",
            "snippet": "The Next, Next Generation\r\n\r\nExperience the future with Motorola XOOM with Wi-Fi, the world's first tablet powered by Android 3.0 (Honeycomb).",
            "price": 150
        },
```

I want  display it as ul li by using template but I'm completely new at this and so I'm stuck.
Here a code that I'm wrote:

```
    <div id="phonesDiv" class="col-md-8"></div>

 <script type="text/template" id="listTemplate">

    <ul>
        <% for (var i=0; i< phones.length; i++) { %>
        <li><%=phones[i].age %></li>
        <li><%=phones[i].name%></li>
        <li><%=phones[i].id%></li>
        <li><%=phones[i].imageUrl%></li>
        <li><%=phones[i].snippet%></li>
        <li><%=phones[i].price%></li>
        <% } %>
</ul>
```

```
  var temp = _.template($("#listTemplate").html());
var getPhones = temp({phones: phones});
 $("#phonesDiv").html(getPhones);
```

Problem is that i instead of displaying image it gives me path of that image:

```
   0
Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi
motorola-xoom-with-wi-fi
img/phones/motorola-xoom-with-wi-fi.0.jpg
The Next, Next Generation Experience the future with Motorola XOOM with Wi-Fi, the world's first tablet powered by Android 3.0 (Honeycomb).
150
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, if you print a url to screen, that is what you will see. If you want to see an image, that is what you have to print, an `<img>`. And use the url as the `src` attribute.

Changing your template to something like this should do the trick:

```
    ...
    <li><img src="<%=phones[i].imageUrl%>" alt="<%=phones[i].name%>" /></li>
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find you answer here:

[how to print array in underscore.js template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648629/how-to-print-array-in-underscore-js-template)

I'm copying the answer in case it will be removed:

> My example looks like this (almost the same as you own):

```
<script type='text/template' id="bunny-template">
  <div> 
     <h5><%= name %></h5>
     <ul>
       <% for(var tag in tags) { %>
           <li><%= tags[tag] %></li>
       <% } %>
     </ul>
  </div>
</script>
```

> with the following Javascript:

```
bunny_data = {
  name: "sprinkles",
  age: 1,
  tags: ['fuzzy','wuzzy']
};

bunny_view = $("#bunny-template").html();
$(body).append(_.template(bunny_view, bunny_data));
```

Just follow the example in your code.

I hope it will help you sort your issue.